# Array variable in JQuery Selector

Tags: jquery, arrays, selector

I have this html:

```
<a href="page1.html" class="menuitem">Page 1</a>
<a href="page2.html" class="menuitem">Page 2</a>
<a href="page3.html" class="menuitem">Page 3</a>
<a href="page4.html" class="menuitem">Page 4</a>
```

---

In a separate .js file, I added some jquery codes:

```
var menuArray = $("a.menuitem");
```

---

I try to run a command from the browser console:

```
$(menuArray[2] + "[href*='page2.html']")
```

It gives me any error about unrecognized expression...

However, this works:

```
$("a.menuitem[href*='page2.html']")
```

What is the correct way to pass array variable to jquery selector? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? `menuArray` is not an array, it's a JQuery object. What is it that you expect `menuArray[2]` to be? Your working example makes it seem like you want the selector used, but that doesn't explain what the array index is supposed to be for

Comment: I was thinking that menuArray is an array of all the anchors, so I could use something like menuArray[i]. 
I was able to enter menuArray[3] in the console and it gives me the result: <a class="menuitem" href="page4.html">

Comment: It is. But what do you think it means to concatenate an anchor with a string?

Comment: Since array indexes start at 0, `menuArray[2]` is the anchor with `href="page3.html"`.

Comment: Say, both $("a.menuitem:eq(2)") and $(menuArray[2]) return the same thing:

<a href="page3.html" class="menuitem">Page 3</a>

So why this doesn't work? $(menuArray[2] + "[href*='page3.html']")

But this does? $("a.menuitem[href*='page2.html']")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.is()` filter method to check the current matched element against a selector range.

```
$(menuArray[1]).is("[href*='page2.html']");
```

https://api.jquery.com/is/

```js
var menuArray = $("a.menuitem");
console.log($(menuArray[1]).is("[href*='page2.html']"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="page1.html" class="menuitem">Page 1</a>
<a href="page2.html" class="menuitem">Page 2</a>
<a href="page3.html" class="menuitem">Page 3</a>
<a href="page4.html" class="menuitem">Page 4</a>
```

Comment: So in other words $(menuArray[1]) doesn't translate exactly to $("a.menuitem:eq(1)") ?

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the `:eq()` selector's behaviour. It's providing a correct way to target elements with the kind of selector ranges you are intending to use. You won't be able to concatenate them like a string because `menuArray[1]` is accessing an array index returning a jQuery object and not evaluating to a string. But to answer your question, they should both be equivalent since array indices and `:eq()` indices both start at `0`

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the links values, use [map](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) :

```
var allMenuItem = $('a.menuitem').map( function() {
  return $(this).attr('href');
}).get();
```